# Java Vector Question

Tags: java, vector

Is the element in the `Vector` a clone/copy of the original?

```
SomeType myVar = new SomeType();
myVar.something = "AStringValue";
myVar.i = 123;

Vector<SomeType> v1 = new Vector<SomeType>();
v1.add(myVar);
Vector<SomeType> v2 = new Vector<SomeType>();
v2.add(myVar);

v1.get(0).i = 321;
```

After this code are these statements true `v2.get(0).i == 321`, `myVar.i == 321`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the `Vector` contains a *reference* to the original object - as does your `myVar` variable. It's very important to understand that a variable (or indeed any expression) can *never* actually have a value which is an object. The value is either a primitive type value (an integer, character etc) or a reference to an object, or null.

When you call `v1.add(myVar)`, that copies the value of `myVar` into the vector... that value being the reference. When you change the object that the reference refers to, that change will be visible via *all* references to the object.

Think of it this way: suppose I have a house with a red door, and give my address to two different people. The first person comes and paints my door green. If the second person comes and looks at the house, he'll see that the door is green too... because he's looking at the same *house*, via a copy of the *reference* (the street address in this case).

(As an aside, is there any reason you're still using `Vector` instead of the more common `ArrayList`? You're obviously using a recent-ish JDK, given that you're using generics...)

Comment: So v2.get(0).i myVar.i will be 321 too?

Comment: @János, yes it will. Btw `Vector` is obsolete - it is preferable to use `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: I'm very happy to hear this :)

Comment: @János: Is there anything stopping you from running the code to find out? ;)

Comment: I just wanted to make sure.
Btw I'm using `Vector` because I'm using a `JList` in an app. and `setListData` takes a `Vector` as parameter.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a clone, it's a reference to the same object.  If you update the one you get from the vector, you're updating the one you put into both vectors.